# Typescript: How to access function from browser console

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

## Context

In `ts/app.ts`, there is:

```
function foo() {
    console.log('Hello Word');
}
```

It compiles successfully with Webpack into `bundle.js` and is loaded with:

```
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

## Question

How to execute `foo` from my browser console?

```
> foo()
Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you have it, you can't access it globally.  But if you want you can do

```
function foo() {
    console.log('Hello Word');
}

(window as any).foo = foo;
```

Then it should be available on the `window` object (which means you can access it either as `window.foo()` or just `foo()` since the `window` object is the global object.

Variables and methods like `foo` are private to the module (ie. file) they're in by default.  You can export them like this:

```
export function foo() {
    console.log('Hello Word');
}
```

And that means you can import them from other modules, i.e.

```
import {foo} from "foo";
foo();
```

However the browser itself doesn't understand that `import` and `export` syntax (*) so they're still not global.  It's webpack that understands that syntax and stitches them all together into a form that the browser can use (in your "dist/bundle.js" file).  Have a look at that file and you'll see the bootstrap code that webpack has inserted.

(*) Edit: [Browsers are starting to support modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules):

Essentially, nothing's global, but that's a good thing because otherwise they could conflict with each other.  i.e. it wouldn't be modular.

Comment: Thank you, can you also explain why it is not available globally?

Comment: I added a lot more detail, but I think the short answer is "it's not supposed to be global" :-)

Comment: I think newer browsers now support module loading. Also, what's that `(window as any`)? Is that valid JS?

Comment: @weltschmerz, no it's not valid JS.  It's valid TypeScript, which knows what methods and properties are on `window` and will object at compile time to `foo`.  When the TypeScript is transpiled down to JS, it will simply be `window.foo = foo;` since JS has no static type info.  I haven't heard about browsers supporting module loading though.

Comment: Huh, you're right: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: I know how TypeScript works, but I looked only at the question's tags, not at the title—my bad. For a moment I thought maybe plain JS had adopted something like that `(window as any)` syntax—as seems to have happened with the module-loading stuff.

Comment: Added the TypeScript tag to the question.